# Nant wont recognize namespace.Properties

Tags: build, nant, csc

I'm trying to use nant to build a solution for a c# project however I am having an issue specifying resources in my build file. I get the error code:
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exists in the namespace 'Darkside'. How can I modify my build file to remove the error?

Here is one of the snippets of code in my source files that is causing the issue:

```
Image enemyImage = DarkSide.Properties.Resources.DarkSide_Asteroid_Medium_Gray;
```

where Darkside is the namespace of the project, and the rest accesses the resources

Here is a snippet of my build file:

```
<target name="build" depends="init" description="compiles the source code">
    <property name="build.dir" value="${project::get-base-directory()}/${project::get-name()}/bin/release/${project.version}${basedir.suffix}"/>        
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <csc target="exe" output="${build.dir}/Darkside.exe" debug="${build.debug}">

        <sources>
            <include name="Darkside/*.cs"/>
        </sources>

        <resources >
            <include name="${project::get-base-directory()}/${project::get-name()}/Properties/**" />
        </resources>
    </csc>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define the `prefix` for the `resources` tag (with dynamicprefix="true").

```
<target name="build" depends="init" description="compiles the source code">
    <property name="build.dir" value="${project::get-base-directory()}/${project::get-name()}/bin/release/${project.version}${basedir.suffix}"/>        
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <csc target="exe" output="${build.dir}/Darkside.exe" debug="${build.debug}">

        <sources>
            <include name="Darkside/*.cs"/>
        </sources>

        <resources dynamicprefix="true" prefix="DarkSide">
            <include name="${project::get-base-directory()}/${project::get-name()}/Properties/**" />
        </resources>
    </csc>
</target>
```

Indeed the `csc` task's [documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/csc.html) states:

> Note: In order to have `<csc>` task generate manifest resource names that match those generated by Microsoft Visual Studio.NET, the value of the prefix attribute of the `<resources>` element should match the "Default Namespace" of the C# project, and the value of the dynamicprefix attribute should be set to "true".

Comment: Even after appending the the default namespace I still get the same error the same number of times.

Comment: @Mozly try with prefix="DarkSide.Properties.Resources" and with dynamicprefix="false".

Comment: @Mozly Ah... and you also need a better include for cs. Something like **include name="Darkside/**/*.cs"**